# how do i display "lists" of different HTML elements in react

Tags: reactjs

im trying to output this multiple times,

```
<div className=mem-container mem-container-1>
      <h2>zone-1</h2>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick added</p>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick removed</p>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick added</p>
      <h4>zone-1 memory sticks total : 10</h4>
</div>
```

came up with the idea of,

```
const MemoryContainer = (memoryZoneNumber) => {
  const memContainerClass = `mem-container mem-container-${memoryZoneNumber}`;
  return (
    <div className={memContainerClass}>
      <h2>zone-{memoryZoneNumber}</h2>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick added</p>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick removed</p>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick added</p>
      <h4>zone-{memoryZoneNumber} memory sticks total : 10</h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

then i do this to output it multiple times,

```
const MemoryContainerCounter = () => {
  const memoryCounterArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    memoryCounterArray.push(MemoryContainer(i));
  }
  return memoryCounterArray;
};
```

is this the right approach in react? or should i use props?

Comment: The "best practice" approach would normaly be to iterate over a map of objects in the parent compoent and instantiate a MemoryContainer for each object.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, maybe you still need to add a prop `key` for each components you want to render, like the code below

```
const MemoryContainer = ({memoryZoneNumber}) => {
  const memContainerClass = `mem-container mem-container-${memoryZoneNumber}`;
  return (
    <div className={memContainerClass}>
      <h2>zone-{memoryZoneNumber}</h2>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick added</p>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick removed</p>
      <p>*timestamp* memory stick added</p>
      <h4>zone-{memoryZoneNumber} memory sticks total : 10</h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const MemoryContainerCounter = () => {
  return <>
    {[1,2,3,4,5,6].map((num) => <MemoryContainer key={num} memoryZoneNumber={num} />)}
  </>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data should originate from either an API or from a hardcoded array of objects.
In both cases, you are dealing with an array of objects.
For example:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, name: Zone1},
  {id: 2, name: Zone2},
  {id: 3, name: Zone3},
];
```

All you have to do is store either the API JSON result or the hardcoded data in a state variable:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([
  {id: 1, name: Zone1},
  {id: 2, name: Zone2},
  {id: 3, name: Zone3},
]);
```

And then iterate over it like so:

```js
const MemoryContainerCounter = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {id: 1, name: Zone1},
    {id: 2, name: Zone2},
    {id: 3, name: Zone3},
  ]);
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((r) => <MemoryContainer key={r.id} memoryZoneNumber={r.id} />)}
    </>
  );
};
```